# spring controller could not recognize

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I tried following code to run sample spring rest application with tomcat7. It works properly, but it could not recognize HelloController. Debugger could not able to reach hellocontroller. http://localhost:8080/Sample/welcome throws 404 error.

```
127.0.0.1 - - - 25/09/2015:23:21:27 +0530 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - - 25/09/2015:23:21:28 +0530 "GET /Sample/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - - 25/09/2015:23:21:34 +0530 "GET /Sample/welcome HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

HelloController.java

```
package com.mkyong.web.controller;


   @Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/welcome**" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView welcomePage() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Hello World");
        model.addObject("message", "This is welcome page!");
        model.setViewName("hello");
        return model;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView adminPage() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Hello World");
        model.addObject("message", "This is protected page!");
        model.setViewName("admin");

        return model;

    }

}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Sample</display-name>
  <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:spring-configured />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

 <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
        <user name="k" password="123" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Here is my mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.web.controller" />

    <bean
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/Pages/</value>
      </property>
      <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
      </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seems to be missing `spring-servlet-config` file and content is in the `spring-security` file. Create a file `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` in `WEB-INF` folder and add the following to it:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:spring-configured />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
</beans:beans>
```

You would remove the moved content from the security configuration file.